# how to set up RGB leds on arduino ethernet with udp instruction?

Tags: arduino

I'm working on a kind of traffic light with RGB LEDs. I try to take a udp value sent from a server to the arduino mega and ethernet shield, then the arduino should change the color of the LED.

Sadly until now, it does not work. In the serial monitor, I find out that the udp packet was received, but then the LED does not work. I was hoping that you guys can help me to figure out why my code isn't working. Thank you in advance! Here is my code:

```
/*
  Web Server
 */

#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <EthernetUdp.h>



    void Color(int R, int G, int B) //set up for the RGB led
    {
          analogWrite(3, R) ;   // Rojo
          analogWrite(5, G) ;   // Green - Verde
          analogWrite(6, B) ;   // Blue - Azul
    }

// Enter a MAC address and IP address for your controller below.
// The IP address will be dependent on your local network:
byte mac[] = {
  0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED};
IPAddress ip(10, 90, 111, 150);

unsigned int localPort = 8888;      // local port to listen on

// buffers for receiving and sending data
char packetBuffer[UDP_TX_PACKET_MAX_SIZE];  // buffer to hold incoming packet,
char ReplyBuffer[] = "acknowledged";        // a string to send back

// An EthernetUDP instance to let us send and receive packets over UDP
EthernetUDP Udp;

// Initialize the Ethernet server library
// with the IP address and port you want to use
// (port 80 is default for HTTP):
EthernetServer server(80);

void setup() {  //seting up the outputs for the rgb 
       pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
       pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
       pinMode(6, OUTPUT);



  // You can use Ethernet.init(pin) to configure the CS pin
  //Ethernet.init(10);  // Most Arduino shields
  //Ethernet.init(5);   // MKR ETH shield
  //Ethernet.init(0);   // Teensy 2.0
  //Ethernet.init(20);  // Teensy++ 2.0
  //Ethernet.init(15);  // ESP8266 with Adafruit Featherwing Ethernet
  //Ethernet.init(33);  // ESP32 with Adafruit Featherwing Ethernet


    // start the Ethernet connection and the server:
  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);

  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }
  Serial.println("Ethernet WebServer Example");

  // Check for Ethernet hardware present
  if (Ethernet.hardwareStatus() == EthernetNoHardware) {
    Serial.println("Ethernet shield was not found.  Sorry, can't run without hardware. :(");
    while (true) {
      delay(1); // do nothing, no point running without Ethernet hardware
    }
  }
  if (Ethernet.linkStatus() == LinkOFF) {
    Serial.println("Ethernet cable is not connected.");
  }

  // start the server
  Udp.begin(localPort);
  server.begin();
  Serial.print("server is at ");
  Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
}


void loop() {


// if there's data available, read a packet
  int packetSize = Udp.parsePacket();
  if (packetSize) {
    Serial.print("Received packet of size ");
    Serial.println(packetSize);
    Serial.print("From ");
    IPAddress remote = Udp.remoteIP();
    for (int i=0; i < 4; i++) {
      Serial.print(remote[i], DEC);
      if (i < 3) {
        Serial.print(".");
      }
    }
    Serial.print(", port ");
    Serial.println(Udp.remotePort());

    // read the packet into packetBufffer
    Udp.read(packetBuffer, UDP_TX_PACKET_MAX_SIZE);
    Serial.println("Contents:");
    Serial.println(packetBuffer);

    // send a reply to the IP address and port that sent us the packet we received
    Udp.beginPacket(Udp.remoteIP(), Udp.remotePort());
    Udp.write(ReplyBuffer);
    Udp.endPacket();

  }
       char numero = packetBuffer;
         if (numero = "1") Color(250, 0, 0) ;
         if (numero = "2") Color(100, 110, 0);
         if (numero = "3") Color(0, 255, 0);
  delay(10);

}
```

From now, it just receives the udp, and while compiling I get:

```
warning: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char' [-fpermissive]
```

but in the end, it compiles.

edited:

i changed the code in this way (just in the final part), and now when i send the udp packet, no matter what i send, i get the green light on, but only the green one, here is the code

```
  void loop() {


// if there's data available, read a packet
  int packetSize = Udp.parsePacket();
  if (packetSize) {
    Serial.print("Received packet of size ");
    Serial.println(packetSize);
    Serial.print("From ");
    IPAddress remote = Udp.remoteIP();
    for (int i=0; i < 4; i++) {
      Serial.print(remote[i], DEC);
      if (i < 3) {
        Serial.print(".");
      }
    }
    Serial.print(", port ");
    Serial.println(Udp.remotePort());

    // read the packet into packetBufffer
    Udp.read(packetBuffer, UDP_TX_PACKET_MAX_SIZE);
    Serial.println("Contents:");
    Serial.println(packetBuffer);
    char numero =  packetBuffer;
         if (numero = 'R') Color(250, 0, 0) ;
         if (numero = 'A') Color(100, 100, 0);
         if (numero = 'V') Color(0, 255, 0);         
    // send a reply to the IP address and port that sent us the packet we received
    Udp.beginPacket(Udp.remoteIP(), Udp.remotePort());
    Udp.write(ReplyBuffer);
    Udp.endPacket();

  }
```

Comment: That warning is telling you: "you've just used pointer to memory as a character", which is legal, pointer is basically a number, so it can be shorted and used as another numeric type (char is 8bit signed integer (or unsigned, depends on compiler and it's settings))

Comment: could it be that you read the color and the led blinks then on next cycle it gets overwritten? Also never use delay, it's only used to teach the beginners. https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BlinkWithoutDelay

Comment: KIIV: so it dont looks like it is the problem jeje, i was wondering if the issue of not turning on the led is releated with the position of the last 3 if , thank u for the time and the awnser

HAROUN: im deleting the delay hehe tank u i will told u if it works, by the way, im really a big newbie beginner on arduino, i have like 1 week of expirience jeje tank u for the awnser

Comment: Also there is a slight difference between = (assigment) and == (equality comparator)

Comment: @mimus I suppose last few lines are actually your code, there is nothing correct. You take address and squeeze it into character variable (not the character on that address), you've got assigments instead of comparation in conditions, you are assigning strings "1", "2"... instead of '1', '2' characters

Comment: @KIIV i change a little the code, it is on the post, i thing this is what u mean?, thank you for the helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend to find some C++ tutorial for starters.

Anyway:

```
char numero =  packetBuffer; // wrong, you are assigning part of address to char, not character at that address... 
if (numero = 'R') Color(250, 0, 0) ; // better but still wrong - numero is set to 'R' and it's also always true
if (numero = 'A') Color(100, 100, 0); // similar to previous
if (numero = 'V') Color(0, 255, 0);   // and again
```

Correct version:

```
char numero =  packetBuffer[0]; // get the first character in buffer
if (numero == 'R') Color(250, 0, 0) ; // compare numero with 'R' 
if (numero == 'A') Color(100, 100, 0); // compare numero with 'A' 
if (numero == 'V') Color(0, 255, 0);   // ...
```

If there is nothing else wrong, that should fix it

Comment: fellow! u are great! tank you so much, i would read a C++ tuto as you sugest,  im more on python and R stuff but now i see a lot of related issues between C and Arduino, again thank you for your help, hugs from mexico